# Sonar not inspecting tests classes in Android project

Tags: android, sonarqube, android-testing, sonarqube-scan

I configured sonar on my android project that contain many flavors. Sonar works fine except that it doesn't show the test coverage in my app. I set sonar properties in my gradle file like that:

```
property "sonar.language", "java"
        property "sonar.sources", "src"
        property "sonar.test", "src/test, src/androidTest/java"
        property "sonar.binaries", "build"

        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", "build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"
        property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/Debug"
        property "sonar.android.lint.report", "build/outputs/lint-results.xml"
```

As i said, I have many flavors, Under the `build/intermediates/classes`, I have a folder for every flavor and the test folder.

Note: the same config works in a project without any flavor !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with binary path. I must specifie the path with the specific flavor. In my case:

```
sonarqube {
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    properties {
//...
property "sonar.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/qa/debug"
property "sonar.java.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/qa/debug"
property "sonar.java.test.binaries", "build/intermediates/classes/qa/debug"
//...
}
}
```

Where qa is my flavor and debug is the build config.

Answer (score 0):

Please add these properties :

```
sonarProperties {
property "sonar.host.url", "http://sonar.someserver.int"
property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://sonar.someserver.int:3306/sonar"
property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
property "sonar.jdbc.username", "*****"
property "sonar.jdbc.password", "*****"

//I added these properties to my gradle.build
property "sonar.projectKey", "GradleAndroidTest"
property "sonar.projectName", "GradleAndroidTest"
property "sonar.projectVersion", "V1.0"
property "sonar.language", "java"
property "sonar.sources", "src"
property "sonar.binaries", "build"
```

}

and  delete the sonar plugin and use the sonar-runner plugin instead.

Comment: Sonar works fine ! it even cover the unit tests in another project that doesn't contain flavors ! this code will works fine only if i haven't flavors